# How to get second key and value from Nested Multimap

Tags: java, data-structures, multimap

I have a complex JsonObject and would like to store the values using a nested Guava multimap because the keys can be duplicated. The problem is how do I access the inner multimap if I have the key to the outer multimap.

This what I have done so far.

```
Multimap<String, Multimap<String, List<ZoneOrders>>> dictionaryfinal;

Multimap<String, List<ZoneOrders>> dictionaryOrders;

dictionaryfinal = LinkedHashMultimap.create();
dictionaryOrders = LinkedHashMultimap.create();
```

then I stored my values like below in a loop through the json response:

```
dictionaryOrders.put(zoneland, zoneorder);                  
dictionaryfinal.put(zonetype, dictionaryOrders);
```

I am able to get the keyset of the outer multimap easily using

```
dictionaryfinal.keySet().
```

After getting one of the keys from the above I want to access the inner multimap linked to the chosen key.

This what I tried so I can have access to the inner multimap:

```
Multimap<String, List<ZoneOrders>> ordinaryold  = LinkedHashMultimap.create();

ordinaryold = dictionaryfinal.get(item);
```

But this doesn't work. I get error incompatible types. Not sure what i am doing wrong.

Comment: What do you mean by 'this doesn't work'? What is the error?

Comment: If you are using the Guava Multimap then the documentation says that the `get(Key k)` method returns a Collection of the values, so to get your nested Multimap you should further iterate into the collection that the `get` returns.

Also, the description of LinkedHashMultimap states: 
_Implementation of Multimap that does not allow duplicate key-value entries and that returns collections whose iterators follow the ordering in which the data was added to the multimap._ 

So it might not be the correct data structure in your case

Comment: Can you put an example of a few outer keys and what values you have for them, because I think you are confused how the structure should actually modelled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that what you want to use is not a `Multimap` but just a normal `Map`.

The `Multimap<K,V>` you are using (presumably the `Guava` one, because you didn't say), is essentially a `Map<K, Set<V>>`.

If instead you use a `Map` your nesting should work:

```
Map<String, Map<String, List<ZoneOrders>>> dictionaryfinal = new LinkedHashMap<>();

Map<String, List<ZoneOrders>> dictionaryOrders1 = new LinkedHashMap<>();
dictionaryOrders1.put(zoneland, zoneorder);      

dictionaryfinal.put(zonetype1, dictionaryOrders1);

Map<String, List<ZoneOrders>> dictionaryOrders2 = new LinkedHashMap<>();
dictionaryOrders2.put(zoneland2, zoneorder2);      

dictionaryfinal.put(zonetype2, dictionaryOrders2);
```

Then if you get the items for `zonetype1` you can get its nested `Map` simply by:

```
 Map<String, List<ZoneOrders>> values1 = dictionaryfinal.get(zonetype1);
```

`values1` will correspond to the inner multimap of `zonetype1` only.

Comment: This returns all values in the inner map and not those associated with the outmap key. but i want to get only those associated with the key selected

Comment: No it does not. It returns the inner multimap associated with the key `zonetype1` only. I added more details to the example.

Comment: it's partly working since I get a list containing one element associated with it. But in the case where the list should contain two or more, it ignores the rest and only returns the last added element. it seems the second element replaces the first.

Comment: How are you adding new items to the inner list of `ZoneOrders`? You should be getting the list and adding to it if it exists. If you replace it with a new list of one element your previous element will be lost.

Comment: sorry for the bad representation :        
       ''' if(dictionaryOrders.containsKey(zoneland)){
          dictionaryOrders.get(zoneland).addAll(zoneorder);
    }else{
             dictionaryOrders.put(zoneland, zoneorder);
             }                                       
   if(dictionaryfinal.containsKey(zonetype)){
                                              dictionaryfinal.get(zonetype).get(zoneland).addAll(zoneorder);                         
    }else{
              dictionaryfinal.put(zonetype, dictionaryOrders);
             }'''

Comment: Well not sure why you are using `addAll`. Without proper context it is difficult to say what you have wrong. You might want to look at the `Map.compute()` method instead of doing all those `containsKey()` and `get()` checks. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#compute-K-java.util.function.BiFunction-

Comment: thank you very much for your time. It works perfectly now. I used  dictionaryOrders.computeIfAbsent(zoneland, k -> new ArrayList<ZoneOrders>())
                                                  .addAll(zoneorder);
                                          dictionaryfinal.computeIfAbsent(zonetype, k -> new HashMap<>()).put(zoneland, zoneorder);